# Multithread Semaphore java

Tags: java, multithreading, semaphore

I'm trying to make a program run two threads through a semaphore. The semaphore must be started to 0. 
At the end should display a message on screen:

```
System.out.println ("string number" + i);
```

where 'i' is the number of the process

My code is:

```
public class Orden extends Thread {
int id;
int num;
static Semaphore semaphore = new Semaphore (0); 
public Orden(int id)
{
    this.id= id;
}
@Override
public synchronized void run()
{ 
    try 
    {
        if(semaphore.availablePermits() == 0){
            semaphore.release(1);
            System.out.println(semaphore.availablePermits());     
        }
        else{
            System.out.println("Thread: " + this.id);
        }

    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        System.out.println(e.toString());
    }

}
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    Orden o1 = new Orden(1);
    Orden o2 = new Orden(2);
    o1.start();
    o2.start();

}
}
```

Where am I wrong? What am I doing wrong?
Thanks

Comment: Not working like you want it to?

Comment: No, the result expected is: 
Thread 2
Thread 1
Because the thread 1 find the semaphore = 0, then release, and the new thread is executed, and unlock the thread 1..
The result i have is: 2 or nothing

Comment: What do you mean "unlock the thread 1"?  There is no synchronization between your threads.  You don't make any calls that would cause one thread to wait for the other.

Comment: Sorry, I edited my post, i testing things and i forgot to write synchronized.. 
Still does not work
I mean that as semaphore is initialized to 0, thread 1 should enter the critical section and locked, run the wire 2, showing "Thread 2", and then unlock wire 1 and show "Thread 1".
My problem is that sometimes I get "thread 2" and other times I do not get anything

Comment: What are you hoping to achieve by declaring your `run()` method to be `synchronized`.  Are you trying to prevent _any_ overlap between the two threads?  In that case, why use threads at all?  The entire point of using threads is that different threads can be doing different things at the same time.  If you don't want them to both be running at the same time, _ever_, then there is no reason to use two threads.

Answer (score 0):

Your run is synchronized but you are synchronized on two different objects o1 and o2 so it is effectively not synchronized. You could use a synchronized block on a static object such as semaphore so they would both be synchronized on the same object.

```
@Override
public void run() {
    try {
        synchronized (semaphore) {
            if (semaphore.availablePermits() == 0) {
                semaphore.release(1);
                System.out.println(semaphore.availablePermits());
            } else {
                System.out.println("Thread: " + this.id);
            }
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println(e.toString());
    }

}
```

Comment: Thanks for your comment... with your solution, i get the first thread in the first position, my english is so bad, but i explain with examples:
With your code, i get this:
Thread 1
Thread 2

The response i want is:
Thread 2
Thread 1

Anyways, thanks

Comment: If you want to guarantee that thread 1 run's first there must be something different about thread 1. They are both started at the same time so that will not be it.  There are many things you could do but you can not really use the semaphore since it is the same for both threads. Makiing one thread run before another is not what Semaphores are used for.

Comment: @JoseMaria, in any case, the way you are using the `Semaphore`, you might as well just use an `int` instead.  You only ever test its value (non-blocking), and increment its value (also non-blocking).  All of the magic in a semaphore is in its `acquire()` method, which your code never calls.